# Move method not changing form postion in form's Open event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to change a form's position on the screen when it opens. I'd like it to open closer to the top of the screen than it currently does.

I've turned the form's Auto Center property off and have had a look at the default values being used (note this is a modal pop-up form).

```vb
Debug.Print "Left: " & Me.WindowLeft; vbCrLf; _
            "Top: " & Me.WindowTop; vbCrLf; _
            "Height: " & Me.WindowHeight; vbCrLf; _
            "Width: " & Me.WindowWidth; vbCrLf & vbCrLf
```

This gives the following output for my particular form:

```
Left: 0
Top: 0
Height: 4140
Width: 15540
```

So I'm assuming if I want to open the form closer to the top of the screen I need to make the `Top` value a negative value.

I've tried various values both negative and positive, but none of them have moved the form; I'm aware that these values are in "twips", so have been using values relative to those shown for the height and width; about -4000 looks to be about what I need for `top`.

Also when I set the `top` value, the `Debug.Print` above shows that the value for `top` has indeed changed to what I've specified, but the form mysteriously stays centred on the screen.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `Debug.Print Me.Moveable` return `True`?

Comment: Yes (blah blah, 15 characters minimum comment, blah blah)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of functions to convert from twips to pixels

```
Public Const LOGPIXELSX = 88        '  Píxeles/pulgadas lógicas en X
Public Const LOGPIXELSY = 90        '  Píxeles/pulgadas lógicas en Y
Public Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

'Emulate the VB property Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
Public Function TwipsPerPixelX() As Integer
Dim hWnd As Long
Dim hdc As Long
Dim Pixels As Integer
   hWnd = GetDesktopWindow
   hdc = GetDC(hWnd)
   Pixels = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX)
   TwipsPerPixelX = 1440 / Pixels
   ReleaseDC hWnd, hdc
End Function
'Emulate the VB property Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
Public Function TwipsPerPixelY() As Integer
Dim hWnd As Long
Dim hdc As Long
Dim Pixels As Integer
   hWnd = GetDesktopWindow
   hdc = GetDC(hWnd)
   Pixels = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY)
   TwipsPerPixelY = 1440 / Pixels
   ReleaseDC hWnd, hdc
End Function
```

If setting Top, Left,... properties don't work, perhaps, you could need to use the SetWindowPos API function

```
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
Private Const HWND_BOTTOM = 1
Private Const HWND_BROADCAST = &HFFFF&
Private Const HWND_DESKTOP = 0
Private Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
Private Const HWND_TOP = 0
Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
Private Const SWP_FRAMECHANGED = &H20        '  Cambió el marco: enviar WM_NCCALCSIZE
Private Const SWP_HIDEWINDOW = &H80
Private Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
Private Const SWP_NOCOPYBITS = &H100
Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Private Const SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = &H200      '  No usar el orden Z del propietario
Private Const SWP_NOREDRAW = &H8
Private Const SWP_NOREPOSITION = SWP_NOOWNERZORDER
Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Private Const SWP_NOZORDER = &H4
Private Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40
```

Here is an example to resize a Form (In your case, remove the SWP_NOMOVE flag, set the top and left parameters and tweak the width and height calculation)

```
Public Sub ChangeWindowSize(ByVal hWnd As Long, Optional ByVal Height As Variant, Optional ByVal Width As Variant)
Dim rcWindow As RECT
Dim rcClient As RECT
Dim DifAlto  As Long
Dim DifAncho As Long

    GetWindowRect hWnd, rcWindow
    GetClientRect hWnd, rcClient
    DifAlto = (rcWindow.Bottom - rcWindow.Top) - rcClient.Bottom
    DifAncho = (rcWindow.Right - rcWindow.Left) - rcClient.Right

    If IsMissing(Height) Then
        Alto = rcClient.Bottom * TwipsPerPixelY()
    End If
    If IsMissing(Width) Then
        Width = rcClient.Right * TwipsPerPixelX()
    End If

    Width = Width / TwipsPerPixelX() + DifAncho  'Convert from twips to pixels and add the borders
    Height = Height / TwipsPerPixelX() + DifAlto  'Convert from twips to pixels and add the borders and caption
    SetWindowPos hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, Width, Height, SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOZORDER
End Sub
```